# Issue : converting String to java.util.Date

Tags: java

When I convert the String `"07/02/2014"` (mm/dd/yyy) to a `java.util.Date` using `SimpleDateFormatter` I get a result of `Sun Dec 29 00:00:00 CAT 2013`.

Here is the code I am running:

```
DateFormat formatter;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
Date exactDate = formatter.parse("07/02/2014");
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: read the documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It must be:

```
  DateFormat formatter;
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  Date exactDate = formatter.parse("07/02/2014");
```

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) explains why.

```
y  Year 
Y  Week year 
D  Day in year 
d  Day in month
M  Month in year 
m  Minute in hour
```

Comment: TL;DR the case of the letters in the format string is not irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date exactDate = formatter.parse("07/02/2014");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you print the Date object you will get that output. Try formatting Date into String for desired format and output.

Try following code:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date exactDate = formatter.parse("07/02/2014");
String date=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(exactDate);
```

Hope this helps.